# How to add mustaches along with attributes in Pug?

Tags: pug, mustache, ractivejs

How can I produce the following HTML in Pug:

```
<p hello="{{there}}" {{extra-attributes}}>hey!</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to set the doctype to html:

```
doctype html
p({{extra-attributes}})
```

At least, that works in a jade online converter.

Comment: I'd try wrapping the mustache in quotes.